# how can I call the (ko.observableArray) from (init) JSON function?

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

Well the title is confusing so I'll give you my code to understand my problem

in knockout tutorials they use functions instead of JSON  I mean like this:

```
data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'somehing'
  },{
    id: 2,
    name: 'somehing else'
  },
]
```

here is my problem

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.dataList = ko.observableArray(data);
    console.log(ViewModel.dataList);
};
```

while on other websites and most of tutorials and projects in github uses JSON

```
var ViewModel = {
     dataList : ko.observableArray(data),
     init: function() {
      console.log(ViewModel.dataList);
      }
};
```

this line

```
     dataList : ko.observableArray(data),
```

when I try to call **dataList** it return this

```
function d(){if(0<arguments.length)return d.Wa(c,arguments[0])&&(d.X(),c=arguments[0],d.W()),this;a.k.Ob(d);return c}
```

and If I try to get its value console will tell me that **dataList** is not defined

but if I pass **data** directly to **dataList** like this (Which is not observableArray anymore) it will give me the full objects values in console

```
     dataList : dataList,
```

the return value in console

```
[Object, Object]
```

how can I call the **ko.observableArray** from **init** function?

I want to follow the tutorials on the web like this one but my issue is the same.

http://opensoul.org/2011/06/23/live-search-with-knockoutjs/

Actually it's not only **ko.observableArray** arrays also I cannot call **ko.observable** objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when I try to call dataList it return this

Your code doesn't **call** `ViewModel.dataList`, it just *accesses* it, which gives you the function (remember observables are functions). To **call** it, add `()`:

```
console.log(ViewModel.dataList());
// Note ----------------------^^
```